# ImportError: No module named build_lib

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the pip install command in this way: `pip install pyverdict --upgrade`, but I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named build_lib`. How can I resolve this?
More detailed error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pyverdict
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/be/c7f5803f599fa74b26ac9b2be385f19f14ce573540371f1f2c1c59a51a80/pyverdict-0.1.3.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-hBPHyv/pyverdict/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        from build_lib import build_and_copy
    ImportError: No module named build_lib
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-hBPHyv/pyverdict/
```

Comment: @C.Nivs yes, i have this error: ```Collecting build_lib
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement build_lib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for build_lib"```

Comment: yep just tried on my 27 test environment

Comment: Looks like this is a project you may have to clone from it's [repository](https://github.com/mozafari/verdictdb/tree/master/pyverdict) and run `python setup.py` manually. `build_lib` is in the top-level of the repo

Comment: Per the [install docs](https://verdictdb.org/download/#python-pyverdict) this also looks like a 3.7 library, rather than 2.7